PyDev debugger running under Eclipse shows message "suicide_when_without_parent"
I am trying to figure out what happens when the PyDev debugger (running under Eclipse) encounters OS.fork(). This was the subject of another post that has not received any response (Eclipse/PyDev debugging with OS.fork())
Since there has been no response, I decided to just push ahead and attempt to debug the application and see what happens. I placed a breakpoint at the beginning of the application and then at the point where OS.fork() is called. I ran the debugger (not the remote debugger, but the "local" debugger from the Eclipse window). The first breakpoint is reached. Then I "Resumed" the session, hoping it would reach the OS.fork() breakpoint (actually the breakpoint is just prior to the OS.fork() call.) However, the debugger appears to hang after a new thread is created and that thread has the message "suicide_when_without_parent". Here is the Eclipse window with that message:

Notice that the debugger controls (i.e., Step Into, Step over, etc.) are no longer showing. So, the debugger seems to have hung. I googled the situation, but could find nothing that helped. I am hoping someone will recognize the problem and help me here.

I think the "debugger controls" only do something when a thread is suspended (at least that's how it works in Java). So you might need to select a thread and suspend it (the pause symbol).

Also what happens between the breakpoints? Can you show the code? Can you include a [mcve]?

Thanks for the reply. Do you mean select the thread and pause it? Since all of the debugger symbols are inoperative, I don't know how to do that. In regards to what happens between breakpoints, this is a huge code. The reason I "Resumed" it after the first breakpoint is one stepping it would take forever to execute between the first breakpoint and the second. To show the code is impractical, since it comprises literally hundreds of python modules.

To give you a feeling for how big the code is, I ran "find . > tree.txt" at the source root. There were 1881 lines, meaning there are 1881 (or there abouts, since a few files were not .py files) modules in the application source.

I meant that if you use threading, you might need to select a thread before suspending. Also, maybe it doesn't work because it's running native code?

The problem is the code is so large, I don't know what it is doing between the two breakpoints. I was surprised that it threw a second thread, since I wasn't aware that it used threading at all. If this sounds a bit odd, my goal is to figure out how to use Eclipse/PyDev to develop the application (which is called salt : https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/index.html). Right now developers use gdb, pdb and pudb to debug. My goal was to figure out how to use an IDE with source code debugging. I tried PyCharm community, but it didn't work out. So, I am trying Eclipse/PyDev.

Can you maybe create a thread dump or similar? Can you try to create a breakpoint in the middle of the two breakpoints and create some sort of manual binary search with breakpoints?

Thanks for the suggestions. The binary search strategy seems promising. I would like to dump the thread with the message "suicide_when_without_parent", but I am new to the PyDev debugger and there isn't much documentation for it. I don't know how to dump a thread. Is there some way to get information on a thread (such as where it was spun)? If I click "Resume" is there a way to stop the debugger before it hangs?

You might want to check Showing the stack trace from a running Python application (or Python thread dump). for thread dumps/getting a stack trace. - Or you could try selecting the threads in the "Debug" view (and possibly expanding the first entry there).

You may also be running into an issue like Eclipse 2022-03, -06 with Pydev ignores breakpoints in threads.

Thanks. The two links you provided are great. I will pursue the instructions they give. I will also look at the "ignore breakpoints post".
